# jQuery function OnClick doesn't work after the custom lazy load function loads the data into the container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I made my own custom lazy load function with jQuery. Everything on Lazy load side works fine. When the html data from the server is appended to the container, the jQuery function **$(".send-comment").on("click");** doesn't work but when its without lazy load its works fine.

**JavaScript**

```
/** JavaScript that executes then hit bottom of the document (Lazy Load functionality)*/ 
$(window).scroll(function () {  
    if ($('body').height() <= ($(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop())) {
        var limit, pageOffSetAttr, url, dataID;
        url = "/ajax/lazy-post.php";
        limit = 5;
        dataID = $("#pageOffSetAttr").attr("data-id");
        pageOffSetAttr = $("#pageOffSetAttr").val();
        pageOffSetAttr = parseInt(pageOffSetAttr) + limit;
        pageOffSetAttr = $("#pageOffSetAttr").val(pageOffSetAttr);
        pageOffSetAttr = $("#pageOffSetAttr").val();
        $.post(url, {pageOffSetAttr:pageOffSetAttr, dataID:dataID}, function(data){
            $(".feeds-unit-container").append(data);
        });
    }
});


/** AJAX the send comment */
$(".send-comment").on("click", function(){
    var callback, context, url, dataAjax, dataID, code, msg;
    callback = $(this).attr("data-add-back-btn");
    url = "ajax/update-status.php";
    context = $("input#new-comment-" + callback ).val();
    dataAjax = $("input#new-comment-" + callback ).attr("data-ajax");
    dataID = $("input#new-comment-" + callback ).attr("data-id");
    $.post(url, {callback:callback, dataAjax:dataAjax, dataID:dataID, context:context}, function(data){
        data = data.split("|");
        code = $.trim(data[0]);
        msg = $.trim(data[1]);
        $("input#new-comment-" + callback ).val("");
        $("#feeds-comment-" + dataID).fadeIn("fast").prepend(data);
    });
});
```

**HTML Side from Lazy Load PHP Script**

```
<div class="row margin0" id="wall-post-#">
    <div class="col-md-4 pad0 parent-profile-image">
    <a href="#">
    <img alt="#" title="#" src="#" width="50" height="50">
    </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 pad0 parent-profile-details">
        <ul class="pad0">
        <li class="name"><a href="#" class="bold">#</a>
        <li class="post"><p>#</p></li>
        <li class="likes">
            &bull;<a href="#" class="post-delete delete-post" data-ajax="delete-post" data-id="#">Delete</a>
            &bull;<a href="#" class="post-comment">Comment</a>
            &bull;<span class="post-time gray">#</span>
        </li>
            <li class="comment bg-default">
          <!-- Comment Box -->
          <li class="stats gray commentbox">
            <div class="row margin0">
              <div class="col-md-4 pad0 commentbox-image">
                  <img alt="#" title="#" src="#" width="30" height="30">
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-8 pad0 comment-details f12" style="width: 90%;">
                <ul class="pad0">
                  <li class="">
                    <p class="margin0">
                        <input id="new-comment-#" type="text" class="pull-left" data-ajax="send-comment" data-id="#" placeholder="Write a comment..."/>
                      <button data-add-back-btn="#"type="button" class="send-comment" title="Send Comment..."></button>
                    </p>
                  </li>
                    </ul>
                    </div>
                            </div>
          </li>
            <!-- ** Comment Box -->
                <!-- Comment Feeds -->
            <li class="stats gray comment-feeds">
                <ul class="pad0" id="feeds-comment-#">
                <li class="name pad2" id="feeds-comment-#">
                <div class="col-md-4 pad0 comment-image">
                  <a href="#">
                      <img alt="#" title="#" src="#" width="50" height="50">
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8 pad0 comment-details f12">
                  <p><a class="bold" href="#">#</a>#</p>
                    <div class="col-md-8 pad0 comment-iteractions f12">
                                        &bull;<a href="#" class="post-delete feed-delete-comment" data-ajax="delete-comment" data-id="#">Delete</a>
                    &bull;<span class="post-time gray">#</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
             </li>
            </ul>
          </li>  
            <li class="stats gray comment-feeds">
                <ul class="pad0" id="feeds-comment-#">
            </ul>
            </li>
            <!-- ***Comment Feeds -->
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to use delegation

change

```
$(".send-comment").on('click', function(....
```

to

```
$(document).on('click', ".send-comment", function(....
```

Answer (score 1):

When you first run `$(".send-comment")` it is empty (i.e. `$(".send-comment").length === 0`, it is not until the content is appended to the DOM, that you can `bind`.

Try adding your current `bind` logic to the `$.post` `callback`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I can't even alert anything after the Lazy load is appended to DOM, it only happens with the Lazy Load DOM data but works perfectly with others.

Comment: Let me try to explain. When you load the page `$(selector)` may be different then after the lazy load. So consider the content you are lazy loading, see what selectors you are trying to use and then run `$(selector)` both before AND after the lazy load in your debugger to see the two sets are different.

Comment: To understand more how @ekeren's version works or how `$.on()` works, realize that `event`s generally percolate to the `document` object. so the `$.on` function listens for that `event` in the DON `trigger`ed by the an event in a `child` elements.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to attach events on dom elements that are not attached to the don now(that will be attached threw Ajax request for example) you should use the following

```
$( document ).on( events, selector, data, handler );        // jQuery 1.7+
```

For example:

```
$( document ).on( "click", ".sent-comment", function(){...});
```

Answer (score 1):

**Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on().**

So for your problem is future DOM could not binding the events properly. Ty to fix for the future DOM element.

The solution is Equivalent to .live() would be something like

/** AJAX the send comment */

$(document).on("click", ".send-comment" , function(){

```
// your code here
```

});